# Taylor sequence for the exponential function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, taylor-series

I tried to implement the Taylor sequence for the exponential function and I get a huge load of errors, which I don't fully understand, as all the code segments in themselves work... Could someone explain the error and a workaround please:

```
top x = map (x^) [0..]
bottom = foldr (*) 1 [1..]
whole x = zipWith (/) (top x) bottom
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: might just me being tired, I worked through 10h today, so it might just be something really dumb, if that is please do excuse me

Comment: your question seem incomplete, how is it related to `Taylor series`? You might want to add more complete ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) code.

Comment: The Taylor sequence is a sequence for calculatign exponential function / sin / cos etc. as stated in the question my code was related to the taylor sequence for the exponential function e^x. I thought that this would be common knowledge, I am sorry if that was not the case. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The problem was that `bottom` wasn't actually a list of all possible factorials.

To solve the problem, I had to use [`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) instead of `foldr`:

```
bottom = scanl (*) 1 [1..]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test each function separately in GHCi to see if it is the same thing you design to be.

For example, your first definition of `bottom`

```
Prelude> bottom = foldr (*) 1 [1..]
Prelude> :t bottom
bottom :: (Num b, Enum b) => b
```

doesn't give a list. This obviously not the right input for `zipWith`

```
Prelude> :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Compared with correct one

```
Prelude> bottom = scanl (*) 1 [1..]
Prelude> :t bottom
bottom :: (Num b, Enum b) => [b]
```

which give a list.